# SvelteKit iFrame load event not firing

Tags: typescript, iframe, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

I have an `iframe` which is loading a local `index.html` file and it does loads the page without any problems, but what I want is to capture an `onload` event of the `iframe` and it is not doing so. Here is the code:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  onMount(() => {
    const iFrame = <HTMLIFrameElement>document.getElementById('frame');

    iFrame.addEventListener('load', () => {
      console.log('loaded!');  // it should print this!
    });
  });
</script>

<iframe
    src="userFiles/index.html"
    class="bg-[#ececec] w-full h-full"
    frameborder="0"
    title="Project"
    id="frame"
    style="color-scheme: dark;"
/>
```

As you can see, there is nothing on the console:

[image]

However, if I write something or just update the code & hit `Ctrl` + `S`, then due to **hmr** it actually triggers the onload function!

[image]

I don't know why is this happening. This seems so strange to me. Here is the file structure, if you want to know:

[image]

However, the same code works on Svelte, so I suppose it is something related to SvelteKit...

---

### Edit:

It really seems something is there with SvelteKit only. I created two new svelte and sveltekit apps forked from the official repos on codesandbox and there too onload on iframe is working on svelte only and not with the sveltekit. Here's the link:

Check the console -> [Svelte](https://ww968m.csb.app/) | [SvelteKit](https://3hjx7l-5173.csb.app/)

Comment: A couple things: Is the onMount function running as expected? Also instead of `getElementById`, try [binding the element](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that that the iframes onload event is already passed when you attach it on the onmount, if you change the iframe srcdoc, the event is captured and the console message is printed.

Try to set the content of the iframe via code after the onload event listener is attached, and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this behavior with vanilla Svelte, that is without using SvelteKit. Thus I suspect it's a side effect of SvelteKit's server-side rendering.

My guess is, your first access to this route is delivered as a readily rendered HTML page, iframe included. This implies component's hydration script could be loaded after iframe's `onload` event, eventually delays the `onMount` callback's firing time.

But even with vanilla Svelte, I believe the firing order is not guaranteed, if you only attach `onload` handler after iframe is mounted. I would suggest you attach at DOM creation, using `<iframe on:load={handleOnLoad} >`

Comment: using ```<iframe on:load={handleOnLoad} >``` isn't triggering the onload event either.

Comment: It really seems something is there with SvelteKit only. I created two new svelte and sveltekit apps forked from the official repos on codesandbox and there too onload on iframe is working on svelte only and not with the sveltekit. Here's the link: [Svelte](https://ww968m.csb.app/) [SvelteKit](https://3hjx7l-5173.csb.app/)